# How to define a Regex/Regular Expression and implementing it through Prolog as automata?

Tags: regex, prolog, automata

I've been tasked to define a regular expression *RE* that produces the following language
only: `L(RE)= {0, 11, 11...1,10, 10…0}`

Then I have to design an automata that accepts the same language generated by the
*RE* before implementing the automata in Prolog.

Comment: This is an interesting exercise! Try to solve it and when you have a specific questions, let us know! :-)

Comment: I have tried, and gotten nowhere. That's why I came here to learn how to do it.

Comment: It is unclear what issue you have. Is it the problem to come up with an automata? Or is this a Prolog-issue? Could you reuse existing code, for instance: https://www.cpp.edu/~jrfisher/www/prolog_tutorial/2_14.html ? Maybe you present what you have tried already.

Comment: The goal is define that regular expression, and then design an automata that accepts the language which then has to be used in Prolog.